# Is the following cron expression means every 45 minutes?

Tags: cron

Am willing to run a script every 45 minute (not the :45th minute of every hour)

e.g. 10:00, 10:45, 11:30, 12:15, and so on.

```
*/45 * * * *
```

Am not sure this is the correct expression.

Comment: I would say it is. other way is to divide a day in 45minute cycles and cron every time you get with that calculation.

Comment: I would say it is not. I believe that separate crontab fields are separate, so `*/45` for minutes is probably the same as `0,45`

Comment: Tested it with */1 * * * * touch /home/user/testfile works. Atleast for Ubuntu 10.04 default crontab

Comment: The `*/45` notation is not specified by the POSIX standard for [`crontab`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/crontab.html), so you need to specify which variant of `cron` (`crontab`) you are using.  (Vixie Cron is documented at [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/cron-guide.xml).  Google search 'crontab linux vixie')

Comment: @Gjordis `/1` works since `(N mod 1) == 0`, i.e. `*/n` in the minutes column means "when the minute mod n is 0"

Comment: [Crontab Guru](https://crontab.guru/#*/45_*_*_*_*)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I *suspect* (edit: I'm pretty sure by now) that it doesn't do what you want: fields are separate, and `*/45` for minutes is nothing more than `0,45`. I would use the following three entries if `*/45` doesn't do the job:

```
0,45  0-23/3 * * *
30    1-23/3 * * *
15    2-23/3 * * *
```

If you take a look at `entry.c` file in vixie cron sources, you'll notice that each *field* of each entry is parsed by `get_list` and represented as bitmaps of allowed values for that field. That almost precludes any "smart" interpretation, as the distinction of `*/45` and `0,45` is lost at this stage... but there is a `MIN_STAR` flag, set at the presence of `*` in minutes (including `*/45`). So we take a look at `cron.c`, a single place where `MIN_STAR` is examined, to learn it's unrelated to our problem. Now we know for sure that `*/45` means "every 45th minute of *every hour*": 0:00, 0:45, 1:00, 1:45 and so on.

There were two answers here confidently stating the opposite, quoting an unfortunate passage in the manual:

> Steps are also permitted after an asterisk, so if you want to say
>   "every two hours", just use "*/2"

We are lucky to have a 24 hour day, containing even number of hours, making "every two hours from 0:00, each day" and "every two hours generally" indistinguishable. Too bad that the manual didn't go far enough to document non-trivial cases, making the impression that `* */22` means every 22 hours. It does not. Star with a step is just a shorthand for a list of values *in the field where it's used*; it doesn't interact with other fields.

Comment: Very interesting. Now, I'm wondering, assuming just two fields, namely, minutes and hours, what would the following pattern resolve to?
`*/45 */2`
I'm thinking the two hours would be divided into 45-minute blocks
Is my thinking right?

Comment: @elimence It's wrong: fields are independent. */45 for minutes means "either xx:00 or xx:45", */2 for hours means "00:xx", "02:xx"..."22:xx". The intersection gives "00:00, 00:45, 02:00, 02:45" etc.

Answer (score 0):

At the basic timing of cron, your system checks once per minute to see if there are any cronjobs to run.  It will look at your crontab, and if it is time to run, poof, it runs!  But every 45 minutes is an interval that will always hit at a 15 minute mark on the clock face.  for example starting from zero the first is 0:45.  Next will be 90 minutes from zero, or 1:30, the next will be 2:15... so easily you can see that the time for each instance you want to execute your script the minute hand will be on 12, 3, 6, or 9. If you execute your script every 15 minutes, and check the hour to see if it is the correct one, you can then execute your script.  You will probably use either a table, or you might also use the modulo feature.  Cheers!