# How to use node-schedule with cron expression strings

Tags: node.js, cron, node-cron

I'm using `node-schedule` and its not working with the cron expression strings.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

schedule.scheduleJob('*/5 * * * * * *', function(){
    console.log(Date.now());
});
```

This just executes once, when the server starts.

I dont want to create `RecurrenceRule` (which worked), instead, just use these strings to create jobs.

Should I just try `node-cron`?

Answer (score 0):

Directly from the node-schedule docs:

> if you only want to do something like "run this function every 5
>   minutes", you'll find `setInterval` much easier to use, and far more
>   appropriate.

It sounds like you are trying to do something it is specifically designed not to do. Perhaps just use `setInterval`?

Comment: No, the pattern I posted was just a basic example. I need a task scheduler, there will be other factors too, not just number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

`node-schedule` doesn't fully support string patterns and they are trying to resolve that [issue](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule/issues/50). You may go ahead with `node-cron` and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499225/i-need-a-nodejs-scheduler-that-allows-for-tasks-at-different-intervals) might help you.