# Is it possible to create timed events using node.js

Tags: node.js, dom-events, timed

Could I use node.js to create timed events that happen on another webpage? For example, could I set up a node.js server to connect to a website and click a certain button every 24 hours? Or is this something that node.js is not capable of? Should I use a different program to do it?

Comment: This might help you with the scheduling of events - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20499504/4774345

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible using **crontab**. For that you need to install a npm called node cron. Please follow the link [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron)