# Schedule multiple functions to run at specific interval in Node JS (CRON JOB)

Tags: mysql, node.js, cron

I want to execute three functions at specific time interval using Node JS. I have gone through this article [I need a Nodejs scheduler that allows for tasks at different intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499225/i-need-a-nodejs-scheduler-that-allows-for-tasks-at-different-intervals)

I have tried with `node-cron` and `node-schedule`. But it is not working !!

My code is like below,

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule')


var fs = require('fs')
var tar = require('tar')

var notification = require('./notification')

let changeInDir = function () {
    console.log('Testing CRON JOB !!!', new Date().toLocaleString())
    fs.watch('./test', (event, filename) => {
        console.log('a', event, 'event occurred.. on file', filename)
    })
}

// schedule a CRON Job
var changeFile = schedule.scheduleJob('4 * * * * *', changeInDir);


// send the Monthly snapshots
var monthlySnapshot = schedule.scheduleJob('5 * * * * *', notification.getViewDetails('Monthly'))

// send the Daily snapshots
var dailySnapshot= schedule.scheduleJob('10 * * * * *', notification.getViewDetails('Daily'))
```

I want that that `monthlySnapshot` will run at `5 seconds` interval while `dailySnapshot` will run at `10 seconds` interval and `changeFile` will run at `4 seconds` interval.

Now `monthlySnapshot` and `dailySnapshot` access MySQL database to get the data and send email accordingly. If I schedule only the `changeFile` and comments others it works fine. But when I try to execute all the three it gives the following error message and crashed.

```
C:\Users\asau\Documents\LeaderBoardNodejs\archlb\src\server\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\schedule.js:174
    this.job.execute();
             ^

TypeError: this.job.execute is not a function
    at Job.invoke (C:\Users\asau\Documents\LeaderBoardNodejs\archlb\src\server\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\schedule.js:174:14)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\asau\Documents\LeaderBoardNodejs\archlb\src\server\node_modules\node-schedule\lib\schedule.js:542:11)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

How to solve that? Any example using `node-cron` or `node-schedule` is OK.

Database access is working fine when I solely use `nodemon notification.js` and correctly send emails. No issues in there.

Comment: Are ```notification.getViewDetails('Monthly')``` and ```notification.getViewDetails('Daily')```  blocking function calls? Are they fetching the data from the database then they are async calls?

Comment: @SagarKarira: yes they are asychronous calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use node cron https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

```
var momentTz = require('moment-timezone');
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var job = new CronJob('*/4 * * * * *', function() {
var a = momentTz.tz("Europe/Helsinki");
 //your logic
}, function () {

   console.log('work ended');
},
true,
'Europe/Helsinki'
);

job.start();
```

it runs every 4 sec

Comment: Please also give your comment. I would like to know also my mistakes.