# Node JS Mail scheduler

Tags: node.js, angular

I am working on an Angular(frontend) and NodeJS(APIs) application. I want to schedule email on particular dates without any external call. I explored node-schedule. But how should I ensure that it runs forever in my NodeJs APIs? Like where should I put the code - in app.js or give it a route?

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right track. You have to use cron service for this. And `node-schedule` is a good choice for this.

So first, make a file named `email-service.js`.

Inside that put your logic.

> **email-service.js**

```
var node = require('node-schedule');

var sendEmail = node.scheduleJob('0 6 * * *', function(){
   console.log('Starting..');
   init(); // write your logic here to send email
});

function init() {
  console.log('Your logic goes here.');
}

module.exports = {
    cronService: cronService
}
```

> **app.js**

In the app.js import `email-service.js`.

```
const emailService = require('email-service')

emailService.sendEmail.start(); // start service..
```

> You can schedule a cron accordingly. Below is the format of the cron.

```
The cron format consists of:

*    *    *    *    *    *
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │    └ day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 is Sun)
│    │    │    │    └───── month (1 - 12)
│    │    │    └────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    │    └─────────────── hour (0 - 23)
│    └──────────────────── minute (0 - 59)
└───────────────────────── second (0 - 59, OPTIONAL)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help. I am using new Date()  as the parameter of schedulejob and the year, month and date value are fetched from database. Doing this results in mails being sent continuously. But if I pass direct values in new Date() it works as intended. Please Help.

Comment: Also please explain the exports

Comment: exports is an object. So it exposes whatever you assigned to it as a module.

Comment: I am working on how to make it cron work dynamic. Once I am done with it, I'll post here.

Comment: @SurjeetBhadauriya hey man can you please take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987333/start-stop-cronjob-on-button-click-in-nodejs-express-app . I badly need help with this.

Comment: Hey @SurjeetBhadauriya, do you have any clue how to handle the timezone conversation? Currently, if I choose in my front-end (Vuejs) a date when an email to be sent, it will automatically convert it in UTC on the back-end. This means, that the message will be sent earlier (in my case 2 hours earlier, cause I am in EEST) and that is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

One more thing, if the application is restarts then your schedule event get cancelled. so it might be a good approach if you save your event in a db and marked them complete or incomplete. And re-schedule your incomplete events at the restart of the application.

I use this to make sure all events runs.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you can achieve with [nodeCron](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-cron).

You may have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499225/i-need-a-nodejs-scheduler-that-allows-for-tasks-at-different-intervals) too

You can shcedule your scheduler to execute on a specific time like

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var j = schedule.scheduleJob('42 * * * *', function(){
  console.log('The answer to life, the universe, and everything!');
});
```

The example above is from node-cron [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron). Please have a look and their github for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use node-schedule node module, it's well documented.

Comment: please provide more detail, maybe an example. OP would find your answer of little help, he already mentioned he is considering node-schedule.

Answer (score 0):

We use [PM2](http://pm2.io) (https://pm2.io/runtime/) - It's a process manager that keeps your process running and has configuration that will allow you to schedule a node job to run according to a cron schedule. There's alot more to it, but if you're looking to improve the operation of your API, this tool is really good - and free.