# Start/stop cronjob on button click in Nodejs Express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cron, scheduler

I have been working on a project which requires the start and stop of cron scheduler when a user clicks on a button on the front end. Basically when a user clicks on a button, the cron job will start. And clicking the stop button will stop the timer. It is as simple as that.

To achieve that, I am making post requests to the Nodejs/Express backend on button click which triggers start/stop function of the scheduler. This is how the endpoint looks like:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

router.post('/scheduler', async (req, res) => {

    // gets the id from the button
    const id = req.body.id;

    try{
         // finds the scheduler data from the MongoDB
         const scheduler = await Scheduler.find({ _id: id });

         // checks whether there is a scheduler or not
         if ( !scheduler  ) {
             return res.json({
                  error: 'No scheduler found.'
             });
         }

         // creates the cronjob instance with startScheduler 
         const task = cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () =>  {
              console.log('test cronjob running every 10secs');
         }, {
              scheduled: false
         });

         // checks if the scheduler is already running or not. If it is then it stops the scheduler
         if ( scheduler.isRunning ) {

             // scheduler stopped
             task.stop();

             return res.json({
                  message: 'Scheduler stopped!'
             });
         }

         // starts the scheduler
         task.start();

         res.json({
              message: 'Scheduler started!'
         });

    }catch(e) {
         console.log(e)
    }
});
```

Right now the scheduler runs perfectly but it doesn't stop on second button click. It keeps on running. I feel like I'm not calling `task.start()` and `task.stop()` at correct places where it would work. And I don't know where the correct places are. I'm actually new to cronjobs.

It would be great if someone tells me what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every time you hit the `scheduler api` a **new instance of cron-job** is made and you are stopping the **newly defined instance of cron-job** not the **previous one**.

Solution is to define the **cron-job out of the scope** of router so that whenever you hit the `scheduler api` the instance won't change

Like this:

```
const cron = require('node-cron');

// creates the cronjob instance with startScheduler 
const task = cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () =>  {
    console.log('test cronjob running every 10secs');
}, {
    scheduled: false
});

router.post('/scheduler', async (req, res) => {

    // gets the id from the button
    const id = req.body.id;

    try{
         // finds the scheduler data from the MongoDB
         const scheduler = await Scheduler.find({ _id: id });

         // checks whether there is a scheduler or not
         if ( !scheduler  ) {
             return res.json({
                  error: 'No scheduler found.'
             });
         }

         // checks if the scheduler is already running or not. If it is then it stops the scheduler
         if ( scheduler.isRunning ) {

             // scheduler stopped
             task.stop();

             return res.json({
                  message: 'Scheduler stopped!'
             });
         }

         // starts the scheduler
         task.start();

         res.json({
              message: 'Scheduler started!'
         });

    }catch(e) {
         console.log(e)
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey man. Do you know if we can create multiple cron jobs which can be stopped by their IDs? For example, I started cron job 1 and 2 and now I want to stop cron job 2 only. How can I stop that cron job only?

Comment: define another cronjob outside out scope like Abhishek suggested for the first cronjob.

Comment: Also don't forget to update scheduler running state in your db after each start/stop

Comment: @RobLittle But how would my function know which cronjob to stop? I will have multiple cronjobs. For example, I am creating an app where an user will be able to create as many bots as they like. And each bot will have its own button to start and stop a bot. If a user presses the button, the cron job will start for that specific bot. And if he presses the same button again then the function will check and find that specific cronjob from multiple other cronjobs (created from other bots) based on the id and stop it. So I need crons with specific id attached to them so tht I can find thm later on.

Comment: @PaulHide how do you do that? I mean what is that thing of a cronjob which I can save into database? Like I tried storing the variable ```task``` in a json file so that I can find it later on when i need to stop it. But it doesn't get saved properly. The stop function isn't found in the json object.

Comment: @Zak thats what the declaration 'const task' is for, control over the cronjob instance.  So, you'd copy the declaration, but name the 2nd, 3rd, 4th cronjob variables 'const task2, const task3, const task4' (or even better, name them appropriately, ie if cronjob assigned to task2 is 'send some email', you should name it 'const emailCron'.  Then you can manipulate that specific object via the reference to emailCron, ie: emailCron.stop(); or emailCron.starat();    hth!

Comment: @RobLittle Thanks so much. I understand now!

Answer (score 2):

The problem might come from the line:

```
    const task = cron.schedule('*/10 * * * * *', () =>  {
```

which, actually, creates a new task **and uses a new Scheduler** if you read the source code of node-cron:
https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/blob/fbc403930ab3165ffef7d53387a29af92670dfea/src/node-cron.js#L29

```
    function schedule(expression, func, options) {
        let task = createTask(expression, func, options);
        storage.save(task);
        return task;
    }
```

(which, internally, uses: https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/blob/fbc403930ab3165ffef7d53387a29af92670dfea/src/scheduled-task.js#L7:

```
    let task = new Task(func);
    let scheduler = new Scheduler(cronExpression, options.timezone, options.recoverMissedExecutions);
```

So, when you call:

```
    task.stop();
```

As far as I understand, what you do is calling the method "stop" of a **brand new task**, not the method stop of the task you launched the first time you clicked the button.

Judging by your code, the problem is that you are not actually using your scheduler while using the task.

PS:
The module also exposes a function that lets you retrieve tasks from its storage: https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/blob/fbc403930ab3165ffef7d53387a29af92670dfea/src/node-cron.js#L58

But as I haven't found any documentation about it, I do not recommend using it.

Comment: hey man thanks for your time. So it got a little bit confusing as my model is also named scheduler. lol. But what I understood from your answer is that the second button click actually creates another task instead of stopping the previous one. So I think there are two things I can do here: ```1: put that task variable somewhere where it won't create the second time.``` or ```2: call getTask() function but there's no documentation on it.``` I think I should go for 1. Do you have any idea how that can be achieved in this whole setup?