# Start and stop NodeJS cron jobs from express API

Tags: node.js, express, cron

I have a node file of cronJob.js:

```
const { exec } = require("child_process");


const cron = require('node-cron');
// Schedule tasks to be run on the server.
cron.schedule('* * * * *', function() {
    console.log("executed")
    exec("node \"C:\\filepath\\callFTP.js\"", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
  });
```

Which will basically execute another node file every one minute. I'm building an API to execute this cron job, however, I'm having trouble referencing this cronjob to stop it in a different API call. For example:

```
app.post('/startSchedulingFTP', function(req, res){
    exec("node \"C:\\filepath\\cronJob.js\"", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        if (stderr) {
            console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
            return;
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
    });
    res.send("success")
})
```

This express API will start the cron script, I'm not sure how to get like an ID to reference this cron job to stop it from another API say ```app.post('/stopSchedulingFTP',...)``. Based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987333/start-stop-cronjob-on-button-click-in-nodejs-express-app), every time a scheduler API is hit, it will create a new instance of a cron job and it suggests that to create a new separate cron job in the same api file. However, as I need to have it separated, the solution is not suitable.

The reason I use the node cron job is that I won't have to worry about the OS of the server in which the application will be installed in.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!