# How to make a Cron job for a typescript class method

Tags: node.js, typescript, cron, node-cron, node-schedule

In Typescript, I have a controller class that has a method that I want to run daily at 5am.

My first thought was to schedule something using node-cron or node-scheduler, but these seem to be strictly for node projects, not typescript.

What I need to happen is a) transpile my entire typescript project into node and then b) Run the method as scheduled.

There doesn't seem to be any explanation on how to do this though.  The explanations I do see are all about running a node.js function on some schedule, such as this one:
[I need a Nodejs scheduler that allows for tasks at different intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499225/i-need-a-nodejs-scheduler-that-allows-for-tasks-at-different-intervals)

The below code illustrates my best approximation at what I'm trying to do.

controller.ts

```
import SomeOtherClass from './factory';

class MyController {
    public async methodToRun(){
        console.log ("King Chronos")
    }
}
```

cron-job.ts

```
import MyController from "../src/controller";

let controller = new MyController();
var cronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
var myJob = new cronJob('00 30 11 * * 1-5', function(){
      controller.methodToRun();
      console.log("cron ran")
});
myJob.start();
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I do use [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) and its [types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cron):

```
npm i cron
npm i -D @types/cron
```

Since there are types available it works pretty fine with TypeScript. In my TypeScript I do something like:

```
import { CronJob } from 'cron';

class Foo {

  cronJob: CronJob;

  constructor() {
    this.cronJob = new CronJob('0 0 5 * * *', async () => {
      try {
        await this.bar();
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    });
    
    // Start job
    if (!this.cronJob.running) {
      this.cronJob.start();
    }
  }

  async function bar(): Promise<void> {
    // Do some task
  }
}

const foo = new Foo();
```

Of course there is no need to start the job inside the constructor of `Foo`. It is just an example.

Comment: Removing "function" from "async function bar(): Promise<void>" removes "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected.ts(1068)".