# Quartz scheduler cron

Tags: quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, cronexpression

i have a job to be scheduled every "min" minutes ( "min" is a variable that indicates the minutes).
I tried the following syntax for the quartz scheduler

String expr = "0 0/"+min+" * * * ?";

the problem is that the job is fired only after "min" and i want it to be scheduled NOW and every "min"

can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance

regards

Comment: You might need to use several CRON expressions, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517795/is-the-following-cron-expression-means-every-45-minutes

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution by using this expression

String expr = "2 "+Integer.toString(Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE)+1)+"/"+min+" * * * ?";

in order to schedule "about" now and after min

Hopes it helps

Bye