# Jenkins scheduled job

Tags: jenkins, cron, task, jobs

Is possible to scheduled a jenkins job to repeat a task every 45 min in a time interval?
Example (Repeat the job every 45 min as many times as possible since 10:00 am to 16:00 pm) - result would be 8 executions.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the job configuration page, search for the section `Build Triggers`. In this section, *enable* `Build periodically` and put the following lines:

```
0,45  0-23/3 * * *
30    1-23/3 * * *
15    2-23/3 * * *
```

Reference: [Is the following cron expression means every 45 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517795/is-the-following-cron-expression-means-every-45-minutes)

*Explanation*:
0,45 means to run at 0 mins and 45 mins for ex. 2 am and 2:45 am

0-23/3 in hour field means that a particular activity has to be performed every 3 hrs. In this case, it means 0, 3, 6, 9,... till 21 hrs (or 2100 hrs). Similarly for others.

So, first line i.e., `0,45 0-23/3 * * *` takes care of 0000 hrs and 0045 hrs. Next time (+45 mins) will be 0130 hrs which will be taken care by `30 1-23/3 * * *` and so on.

You can check the cron format details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks!! I´ll test it. I cant figure out how this expression works.... What is the end´s interval number? Did not execute the task indefinetely?

Thanks again!!

Comment: Check the explanation in my answer.

Comment: I have tested this expresion, and works fine launching the job every 45 min, but never ends. How can I set an end time (5am for example) in the expression?