# Cron expression to execute every 45 minutes and not 45th minute of the hour

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to generate a cron expression which executes every 45 minutes.

I have created the following expression.
0 0/45 * 1/1 * ? *

But this expression fires every 45th minute of the hour. 
Ex: 10:45,11:00,11:45,12:00 etc.

But can we generate an expression which fires for example,
10:45,11:30,12:15 etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is the following cron expression means every 45 minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14517795/is-the-following-cron-expression-means-every-45-minutes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cron expression does not support for every 45th minute. You can use with `Trigger`:

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .startAt(startTime)
                .withSchedule(
                        CalendarIntervalScheduleBuilder
                                .calendarIntervalSchedule()
                                .withIntervalInMinutes(45)
                                .withMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that directly.

```
0,45 */3 * * * ? *
30 1,4,7,10,13,16,19,22 * * * ? *
15 2,5,8,11,14,17,20,23 * * * ? *
```